# PROBLEM WITH COMPILER C/ PLEASE HELP ME

Tags: programming, c, execute-command, compiler

My first language is Spanish, and my use of English is not the best, but I need some assistance in debugging the following program code since it produces an error when compiled.

CODE:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int edad[tope], estatura[tope], rut[tope];
    int i;
    FILE * direccion_de_memoria_del_csv;

    for (i = 0; i<tope; i++)
    {
        printf("=== PERSONA %d ===\n", i);
        printf("ingrese edad?");
        scanf("%d", &edad[i]);
        printf("ingrese estatura ?");
        scanf("%d", &estatura[i]);
        printf("ingrese rut ?");
        scanf("%d", &rut[i]);
    }

    /*Nota: c:/tmp/ de existir en el disco*/
    direccion_de_memoria_del_csv = fopen("C:/tmp/datos.csv", "w");
    fprintf(direccion_de_memoria_del_csv, "edad,estatura,rut\n");
    for (i = 0; i < tope; i++)
    {
        fprintf(direccion_de_memoria_del_csv, "%d,%d,%d\n", edad[i], estatura[i], rut[i]);
    }
    fclose(direccion_de_memoria_del_csv);
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
   Taller.c:6:11: error: 'tope' undeclared (first use in this function)
      int edad[tope], estatura[tope], rut[tope];
               ^~~~
    Taller.c:6:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

EXECUTE BY CONSOLE WITH COMMAND `gcc Taller.c -o Taller`

Comment: You did not define `tope` - when initializing your arrays and also running through your for-loop, the compiler does not know what `tope` is and therefore cannot determine the size of the arrays. Set it to a constant integer or just put in an integer directly.

Comment: C is Procedure Oriented Programming Language. It expects that you've defined the datatype of **tope** but you haven't.

Comment: @Wiggles  Your comment is actually the answer to the question that was posed.  You should add it as an answer rather than as a comment.

Comment: Question is off topic.  There is no c:\tmp on a linux box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not define `tope`. 
When you initialize your arrays and also when you run through your for-loop the compiler does not know what `tope` is and therefore cannot determine the size of the arrays.  Set it to a constant integer (before you initialize your arrays)

```
const int tope = 42
```

or just directly put in an integer in the place of `tope`.

@CentaurusA Sorry for not directly submitting the comment as an answer. It seemed not right at first.